# multi queries meteor on server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I try to make a query that will check two other collections. I try the module publishComposite but I didn't work. I tried this code but it did work out. Can somebody please help me by finding in the collection "voorraad" items that are no reserved in the collection "reserveringen". This is the code setup

```
  Meteor.publish('Voorraad_subs', function(leverancier, start, eind) {
  return Verhuurmodule.find({leverancier: leverancier}, function(lever) {
    return Voorraad.find({module: lever._id, status: 1}, function(voor) {
      var tel = Reserveringen.find({
        object: voor._id,
        $or: [
          {
            $and: [
              {
                start: {
                  $lte: start
                },
                eind: {
                  $gte: start
                }
              }
            ]
          }, {
            $and: [
              {
                start: {
                  $lt: eind
                },
                eind: {
                  $gte: eind
                }
              }
            ]
          }, {
            $and: [
              {
                start: {
                  $gte: start
                },
                eind: {
                  $lt: eind
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }).count();
      if (tel > 0) {
        return voor;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The PublsihComposite code

```
Meteor.publishComposite('Voorraad_subs', function(leverancier, start, eind) {
  return {
    find: function() {
      // Find top ten highest scoring posts
      return Verhuurmodule.find({
        leverancier: leverancier
      });
    },
    children: [{
      find: function(post) {
        return Voorraad.find({
          module: post._id,
          status: 1
        });
      },
      children: [{
        find: function(voorraad) {
          return Reserveringen.find({
            object: this._id,
            $or: [{
              $and: [{
                start: {
                  $lte: start,
                },
                eind: {
                  $gte: start,
                }
              }]
            }, {
              $and: [{
                start: {
                  $lt: eind,
                },
                eind: {
                  $gte: eind,
                }
              }]
            }, {
              $and: [{
                start: {
                  $gte: start,
                },
                eind: {
                  $lt: eind,
                }
              }]
            }]
          });
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show your publishComposite code that didn't work instead. This code you have here is too far from anything that would ever work. Also please show examples of the data from both collections that you wish to join and how they are related to each other.

Comment: Here is the code of puplishComposite. I add the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this._id` isn't pointing to the `_id` of the object you're iterating over in the 3rd nested child.

You can also simplify your interval logic with the start and end times.

Here's an attempted correction/simplification:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('Voorraad_subs', (leverancier, start, eind) => {
  return {
    find() {
      return Verhuurmodule.find({ leverancier });
    },
    children: [{
      find(post) {
        return Voorraad.find({ module: post._id, status: 1 });
      },
      children: [{
        find(voorraad) {
          return Reserveringen.find({ object: voorraad._id,
            $nor: [{
              start: { $gt: eind }, // exclude all reservations that begin after the interval
              eind: { $lt: start }  // and all those that finish before the interval
            }]
          });
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

However: I'm also suspicious of your notation. For example:

```
return Voorraad.find({ module: post._id, status: 1 });
```

is `module` an `id`? I'd expect to see something like `moduleId` there.

And the same with:

```
return Reserveringen.find({ object: voorraad._id, ...
```

Is `object` an `id`? Or did you mean `objectId`?